# Formatting ggplot2 axis labels with commas (and K? MM?) if I already have a y-scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

I am trying to format Cost and Revenue (both in thousands) and Impressions (in millions) data for a ggplot graph's y-axis labels.

My plot runs from 31 days ago to 'yesterday' and uses the min and max values over that period for the `ylim(c(min,max))` option.  Showing just the Cost example,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(TTR)

set.seed(1984)

#make series
start <- as.Date('2016-01-01')
end <- Sys.Date()

days <- as.numeric(end - start)

#make cost and moving averages
cost <- rnorm(days, mean = 45400, sd = 11640)
date <- seq.Date(from = start, to = end - 1, by = 'day') 
cost_7 <- SMA(cost, 7)
cost_30 <- SMA(cost, 30)

df <- data.frame(Date = date, Cost = cost, Cost_7 = cost_7, Cost_30 = cost_30)


# set parameters for window
left <- end - 31
right <- end - 1

# plot series
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Cost))+
geom_line(lwd = 0.5) +
geom_line(aes(y = Cost_7), col = 'red', linetype = 3, lwd = 1) +
geom_line(aes(y = Cost_30), col = 'blue', linetype = 5, lwd = 0.75) +
xlim(c(left, right)) + 
ylim(c(min(df$Cost[df$Date > left]), max(df$Cost[df$Date > left]))) +
xlab("")
```

[image: ggplot output]

I would a) like to represent thousands and millions on the y-axis with commas, and b) like those numbers abbreviated and with 'K' for thousands or 'MM' for millions. I realize b) may be a tall order, but for now a) cannot be accomplished with

`ggplot(...) + ... + ylim(c(min, max))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)`

Because the following error is thrown:

```
## Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which
## will replace the existing scale.
```

I have tried putting the `scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)` section after the `geom_line()`layer (which throws the error above) or at the end of all the ggplot layers, which overrides my limits in the `ylim` call and then throws the error above, anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For the comma formatting, you need to include the `scales` library for `label=comma`. The "error" you discussed is actually just a warning, because you used both `ylim` and then `scale_y_continuous`. The second call overrides the first. You can instead set the limits and specify comma-separated labels in a single call to `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Cost))+
  geom_line(lwd = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Cost_7), col = 'red', linetype = 3, lwd = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Cost_30), col = 'blue', linetype = 5, lwd = 0.75) +
  xlim(c(left, right)) + 
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits=c(min(df$Cost[df$Date > left]), 
                                           max(df$Cost[df$Date > left])))
```

Another option would be to melt your data to long format before plotting, which reduces the amount of code needed and streamlines aesthetic mappings:

```
library(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(df, id.var="Date"), 
       aes(x = Date, y = value, color=variable, linetype=variable))+
  geom_line() +
  xlim(c(left, right)) + 
  labs(x="", y="Cost") +
  scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits=c(min(df$Cost[df$Date > left]), 
                                           max(df$Cost[df$Date > left])))
```

Either way, to put the y values in terms of thousands or millions you could divide the y values by 1,000 or 1,000,000. I've used `dollar_format()` below, but I think you'll also need to divide by the appropriate power of ten if you use `unit_format` (per @joran's suggestion). For example:

```
div=1000

ggplot(melt(df, id.var="Date"), 
       aes(x = Date, y = value/div, color=variable, linetype=variable))+
  geom_line() +
  xlim(c(left, right)) + 
  labs(x="", y="Cost (Thousands)") +
  scale_y_continuous(label=dollar_format(),
                     limits=c(min(df$Cost[df$Date > left]), 
                              max(df$Cost[df$Date > left]))/div)
```

Use `scale_color_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual` to set custom colors and linetypes, if desired.

[image]

Comment: Sigh.  Well that's frustratingly simple.  I'll wait to check off as answer to see if anyone posts for (b), but much thanks for now.

Comment: @D8Amonk Try looking at `unit_format` in the **scales** package for (b).

Comment: @joran can that option be thrown into the `scale_y_continuous` call?

Comment: @D8Amonk Pretty sure. `label = unit_format(unit = "K")`.

Comment: @joran how can label = two params (comma and unit_format)?

Comment: @D8Amonk `unit_format` itself calls `comma`. Just use `unit_format`.

Comment: "Well that's frustratingly simple." Everything in R is simple...once you know the secret!

Comment: when I divide my Cost by k after assigning `k <- 1000` it just keeps the same values and puts `Cost/k` as the y-axis label....?

Comment: Can you paste the full updated code into your question?

Comment: @joran `unit_format` appears to be very useful; however, I have noticed that `scale_y_continuous(label = unit_format(unit = "m", scale = 1e-6))` would abbreviate 6,000,000 to `6 m`. It's not a major thing but in the UK it would [*slightly more common*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149201/141211) to use **`6m`** with no space in between.

Comment: @Konrad, Not sure how it can be done, but it **might be** possible to use a back space character. Something like `scale_y_continuous(label = unit_format(unit = "\bm", scale = 1e-6))`. I tried searching but could not find how to do that in R.

Comment: @joran @Konrad You can use the `sep` field available in `unit_format` to get rid of the space. For example, `unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6, sep = "")`. See (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/unit_format)

Answer (score 24):

I just found the solution. It does not work with `"label = comma"`. Please try this solution:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

It works well for me.

Answer (score 4):

The `unit_format()` function highlighted by @joran has now been depreciated within the `scales` package and replaced with `label_number()`. It defaults to using a space as a separator, change this with the `big.mark=` argument. Use the `prefix =`  and `suffix =`  arguments to add characters before and after, and the `scale =`  argument to multiple the numbers by a scaling factor (so in many cases you want a negative exponent here).

The problem that @konrad notes with a space between the number and the suffix no longer seems to exist. If you want a space, include it in the suffix argument `suffix = " M"`.

So for example to show 1234000 as £1,234k on the the y axis `scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(prefix = "£", suffix = "k", scale = 1e-3, big.mark = ","))`

As comma separators are so commonly used there is a convenience function `label_comma` which sets `big.mark = ","`. Or, for even less typing, the `comma()` function is exactly the same.

One gotcha is that the `scales` package is not loaded as a dependency with `library(ggplot)`, you have to load it separately, or as @Aurora points out in their answer, by prefixing the function with `scales::`

https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number.html