# in R use `$` and `K` as a y-axis labels for thousands of dollars

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

[This older stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713351/formatting-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-commas-and-k-mm-if-i-already-have-a-y-sc) explains how to change your y-axis to `K` for thousands instead of `,000`. It also explains how to put a dollar sign on the y-axis labels with `scales::dollar`. My trouble is in combining the two ideas in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
set.seed(200)
df <- tibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
             Values = c(runif(12, 200000, 800000)))

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(label = unit_format(unit = "K", scale = 1e-3, sep = "")) + 
  # scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar) +  # line 10
  NULL
```

I can use either line 9 *or* line 10 above, but not both simultaneously. How do I incorporate both line 9 and 10 into a single line? I want to transfer, as an example, `115,000` into `$115K`.

Comment: `unit_format(prefix = "$", unit = "K", scale = 1e-3, sep = "")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `scales::dollar_format` to achieve what you're going for:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(scale = .001, suffix = "K"))
```